# preciso passar esse cod para angularjs alguem sabe me ajudar

Tags: angularjs

Alguém sabe passar isso para angular?

```
$(document).on(
    'keydown',
    function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey
            && e.which === 83) {
        $(".btnSalvarRegistro").click();
    }
);
```

por favor me ajude.

Answer (score 0):

É recomendado pela documentação do AngularJS fazer o controle de eventos via diretivas, mas postarei dois exemplos para que você veja qual se adequará a seu caso:

Via **Diretiva**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('shortcut', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    link:    function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs){
      $document.on('keypress', function(e){
      console.log(e.ctrlKey)
      console.log(e.altKey)
      console.log(e.which)
      console.log("--------")
          if(e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && e.which === 83){
            scope.$apply(scope.changeMessage("letra S +  apertada"));
            e.preventDefault()
          }
      });
    }
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.changeMessage = function(m){
  $scope.message = m
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <shortcut></shortcut>
  <h1>View keys pressed</h1>
  <input type="text">
  {{message}}
</div>
```

Via **Controller**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('KeydownController', function KeydownController($scope, $document) {
  $scope.counter = 0
  $document.on("keypress", function (event) {
  
      // AO APERTAR ENTER
      if(event.which === 83) {
          
          $scope.$apply($scope.counter++);
          event.preventDefault();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="KeydownController">
  <input type="text">
  {{counter}}
</div>
```